# Оформление прямой речи, включающей длинное повествование

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, диалог

Правильны ли данные варианты оформления прямой речи (кавычки/тире)?

1. Сомнения в первом варианте: использование кавычек  отчуждает первую реплику от рассказчика (то, что в кавычках как будто звучит само по себе, как радио, а то, что после тире, уже живой человек говорит), и целостность восприятия нарушается.
2. Сомнения во втором варианте: склоняюсь больше к нему, но из-за двух тире реплики начинают выглядеть как диалог, хотя перед нами монолог. Кажется, в художественной литературе такой вариант встречался...

1) *Он  рассказал им такую историю:*

*"Текст истории*

*текст истории*

*текст истории".*

*-- Итак, -- закончил он рассказывать историю, -- хорошенько запомните всё это.*

2)  *Он  рассказал им такую историю:*

*-- Текст истории*

*текст истории*

*текст истории.*

*-- Итак, -- закончил он рассказывать историю, -- хорошенько запомните всё это.*

Comment: Здесь нет диалога, лучше бы не обойтись закавыченной прямой речью (третий вариант) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Длинное повествование оформляют или как монолог -  с абзаца и с тире, или как прямую речь - с кавычками, или без двоеточия и без кавычек как несобственно прямую речь(от первого лица, но совмещённую с авторской):

Он рассказал им такую историю.Текст истории

текст истории

текст истории.

-- Итак, -- закончил он рассказывать историю, -- хорошенько запомните всё это.